Exclude URL from XML sitemap in Shopware 6
I am searching for a way to manipulate the auto-generated sitemap in a Shopware 6.5 environment. Specifically I want to remove the URL of some products from it.
Things I already considered without success:

the product admin pages don't have any setting for the sitemap
the global admin settings don't have any settings related to the sitemap
codewise, there is no subscriber event to hook into the XML generation.

Is there some other way?

There is a configuration setting to exclude URLs from the sitemap:
shopware:
    sitemap:
        excluded_urls:

Create a file under config/packages/, for example z-sitemap.yaml, and add your product.
shopware:
    sitemap:
        excluded_urls:
            -   salesChannelId: '<saleschannel-id-where-the-product-is-in>'
                resource: 'Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEntity'
                identifier: '<product-id>'

Clear your cache:
bin/console cache:clear

Then regenerate the sitemap with the console command:
bin/console sitemap:generate


The explanation for the configuration of this setting is not included in the documentation, I have added a PR https://github.com/shopware/docs/pull/1481

I realized you can also decorate a service. Decorating the core's SitemapExporter class enables you to apply your own logic on a just generated XML sitemap.
Straight forward if you know how decorations work. Here's a skeleton:
Resources/config/services.xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Service\SitemapExporter"
  decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Sitemap\Service\SitemapExporter">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Service\SitemapExporter.inner"/>
</service>

Service/SitemapExporter.php
class SitemapExporter implements SitemapExporterInterface
{
    public function __construct(private SitemapExporterInterface $innerService) {
    }

    public function generate(SalesChannelContext $context, bool $force = false, ?string $lastProvider = null, ?int $offset = null): SitemapGenerationResult
    {
        $generateResult = $this->innerService->generate($context, $force, $lastProvider, $offset);

        if($generateResult->isFinish()) {
            // Do something with the generated sitemap files
        }

        return $generateResult;
    }
}

